# Don't display list element until link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone tell me if there is either a CSS (preferably) or JS solution to not displaying list element id="two" in the code below until link "#two" in the following  has been clicked (removing element id="one" in the process). In this, note that I need the list element to not be displayed at all rather than simply hidden in the page view.

I'm happy to explain why I need this bizarre behaviour if someone can provide a working solution; I'm just thinking around a problem in another, unanswered, SO question of mine...

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul id="gallery-interior">
<li id="one"><img src="../images/normal_1"></li>
<li id="two"><img src="../images/notmal_2"></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
<a href="#one"><img src="../images/thumb_1.jpg"></a>
<a href="#two"><img src="../images/thumb_2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: post your javascript too

Comment: ***not be displayed at all rather than simply hidden*** looks like you want it not to even be added to the DOM? Clicking the link will add it to the DOM (as well as showing it)?

Comment: @Ejay What javascript?

Comment: @user3492855 I thought so!

Comment: @Ejay Pointless comments. See accepted answer below for how to answer a question.

Comment: 1. you're taking my comment as an answer. 2. The only thing pointless at this page is your question. You've posted your requirements as if you're entitled to an answer without showing ANY research and/or effort and want people on SO to write javascript for you. This website isn't meant for resolving peoples' issues that they could resolve themselves by at least reading a book on the topic. And when somebody asks you to show your effort, you tell them "what effort?", and "pointless" later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a solution for you using jquery.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*="two"]').click(function() {
    $("#one").hide();
    $("#two").show();
});
})
```

Here's a fiddle
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tg3D9/)

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I need, but your fiddle shows this solution to be one-time only. When I click the 'Element 2' link, 'Element 1' disappears from the list as intended. However, when I click the 'Element 1' link again nothing happens, and the expected behaviour is that the 'Element 1 list element would reappear and '2' revert to 'display: none' once more. See also my comment to Abram above. If this behaviour can be provided (coded for a list of five items, say), then that would be the answer.

Comment: @user3492855 I've updated an other version hope this is what you want.http://jsfiddle.net/Tg3D9/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (assuming you add id='links' to the div containing links):

```
<script>
$('#links a').on('click', function(){
    $('#gallery-interior li').hide()
    $($(this).attr('href')).show()
})
</script>
```

First I hide all the li elements in gallery-interior. I noticed you conveniently have the selector for the element you want to show in the href attribute, so I simply pass that to jquery.

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I should rephrase my question. I don't actually want to "...hide all the li elements in gallery-interior", but just all the elements other than the first element ("one"). When link "two" is clicked (or "three" or "four", assuming a longer list), I need all the list elements other than the clicked one to be removed from display.

Comment: That's what this code does. Shows the li associated with the button that's clicked on, and hides the others.